# Optional arguments in Python Script for Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++, scintilla, optional-arguments

I'm trying to automize deleting of some text on a HTML code I'm editing on Notepad++. I've figured out the plugin "Python Script" would be a good option.

It seems to me I should use Editor.rereplace working as follow:

```
Editor.rereplace(search, replace[, flags[, startPosition[, endPosition[, maxCount]]]])
```

Only problem is that I want to use the optional argument "maxCount" but not "flags", "startposition" and "endposition"

I've tried coding this:

```
Editor.rereplace("old", "new", maxCount=1)
```

That does not work, I guess because it's not really Python but Scintilla language. So I've looked out on Scintilla documentation and it seems to me, optional argument does not exist "naturaly" in Scintilla.

Comment: If you're just trying to replace one string with another, you don't really need to do python. Notepad++ search and replace can happily do that for you.

Comment: Actually it is more tricky than that, I need to replace not the first term that appears in the code but the second term. (and eventually the third, the forth, etc.. term if there is one)

Also I need to replace only the first term but no the terms that come after. (that is a different term)

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and output text? It still feels like there would be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Actually that is a long code but what I want to do is to put two or more different html codes I got from MailChimp in a single head.

So I need to keep the first <html>, <body>... and erase the next ones and then I need to erase the first </html>, </body>... and keep only the last one.

I hope you'll get what I'm trying to do

Comment: so why not just Step1: delete every occurrence of `<html>` `</html>` `<body>` and `</body>` using find and replace and then Step2: insert some tags at the top and bottom manually?

Comment: Actually I'm not doing this for myself but for someone who doesn't know anything about coding and I'm pretty sure letting her do the job by herself could led to some mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is defined as `[opt1 [opt2 [opt3]]]` and not `[opt1] [opt2] [opt3]` which means you cannot use opt3 without also specifying opt1 and 2. Why not just supply values for the flags, start and end positions that work for you?

I would try:

```
Editor.rereplace("matchRegex", "replaceWith",0,0,1,1)
```

Where:

```
Flags: 0
Start: 0
End: 1
MaxCount: 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but what you suggest did not work, since the term I am looking is for is not in the first line.

I'm now going to look for a way to get the number of lines of code in my html code to have an end position that works for every type of code I want to modify.

Comment: Anyway I've tried

    editor.rereplace("</center>", "",0,1,editor.getLineCount(),1)

That does not work I don't know why, maybe because of the flag value? (I do not understand anything what that is)
Note that I do not have anything written in the console, so it seems like it is working fine it just does not change the text.

Nb: getlinecount does works fine, I've tried this:

    y = editor.getLineCount()
    notepad.messageBox(str(y))

(the message box give me the exact number of code lines)

Comment: > `endPosition` is the binary position to end the search. Use `Editor.positionFromLine()` to get the binary position from the (zero indexed) line number. http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html

Comment: also, you might have to set `re.MULTILINE` in flags if you want to search for a pattern in several lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you've spent to help me, that works just fine :)

I hope this thread will help some other people

Comment: Just one last question: how can I be able to modify not the first term but the one that appears after?

I thaught there would be a Scintilla function to get the code line where the first time appears but I can't find one. With this info I would have been able to start my rereplace at the line after.

Do you have any idead how I could do that?